# Running only failed test cases in Cypress

Tags: cypress

While running Cypress scripts, some of the cases are getting failed. I want to run only those failed cases to run again.
How can I run only failed test cases in Cypress?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not yet possible in the UI. There is an open issue tracking that request: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4886. For automatic retries during headless builds, see https://github.com/Bkucera/cypress-plugin-retries

Answer (score 2):

As long as its not integrated directly in Cypess, you can use a npm package like [`cypress-run`](https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-run)

`npm install cypress-run --save`

Then edit then run command in the `package.json` and replace the command
`cypress run` by for example `cypress-run --retries 4`, this will retry the failed tests 4 times

Answer (score 1):

Cypress has released version 5.0 which has support for retries, see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries.html for more information

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your `cypress.json` file.

```
{

"retries":2
}
```

It will retry your failed Test case for twice.